# Accessing the Portainer web UI via HTTPS on port 9443 using Traefik

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik, portainer

I am stuck and after a lot of google, documentation reading, testing, and even resorting to ChatGPT I am turning to the community for help.

**Context:**

I am rebuilding my little home server, improving configurations in general and moving from Cloudflared Tunnels to Traefik as I wanted to learn how to use it and serve video without potential issues from Cloudflare.

Right now I'm struggling with Portainer... I would like to be able to access the Portainer web UI through Traefik (eventually with something like Teleport for better authentication).

Below I have outlined my docker compose files for Traefik & Portainer as well as my Traefik configuration file.

*Other info*

- My system is running Ubuntu 22.04.3
- UFW is configured to allow ports 80 & 443
- Router is forwarding ports 80 and 443 to the correct machine
- Portainer is configured with "Force HTTPS" enabled

---

**The Problem:**

I am able to connect to Portainer by accessing the machine directly at 192.168.1.X:9443, however whenever I try to connect to is through *portainer.mydomain.com* it returns 500 "Internal Server Error".

I've looked at the reqeuest/response values in dev tools, however they don't reveal anything useful (at least to me)

I'm hoping that it's a simple error and the gap in my knowledge can be filled.

Please let me know if you need any more information about configurations or if there is another answer on here I didn't find.

---

**Configurations:**

*Portainer (compose file)*

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - private
    ports:
      - 9443:9443
    labels:
      # Frontend
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=web, websecure'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.mydomain.com`)' # Removed sensate information
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=production'
      - 'traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9443'
      - 'traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https'

volumes:
  portainer_data:
    external: true

networks:
  private:
    external: true
```

*Traefik (compose file)*

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  traefik:
    image: 'traefik'
    container_name: 'traefik'
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - '/etc/traefik:/etc/traefik'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
      - 'traefik-ssl-certs:/ssl-certs'
    networks:
      - gateway
      - public
      - private

volumes:
  traefik-ssl-certs:
    external: true

networks:
  gateway:
    external: true
  public:
    external: true
  private:
    external: true
```

*Traefik (configuration file)*

```yaml
global:
  checkNewVersion: true
  sendAnonymousUsage: false

# -- (Optional) Change Log Level and Format here...
#     - loglevels [DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, CRITICAL]
#     - format [common, json, logfmt]
log:
  level: DEBUG
  format: common
  filePath: /var/log/traefik/traefik.log

# -- (Optional) Enable Accesslog and change Format here...
#     - format [common, json, logfmt]
# accesslog:
#   format: common
#   filePath: /var/log/traefik/access.log

# -- (Optional) Enable API and Dashboard here, don't do in production
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure: true

# -- Change EntryPoints here...
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80

    # -- (Optional) Redirect all HTTP to HTTPS
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure
          scheme: https

  websecure:
    address: :443

  # -- (Optional) Add custom Entrypoint
  # custom:
  #   address: :8080

# -- Configure your CertificateResolver here...
certificatesResolvers:
  staging:
    acme:
      email: email@gmail.com # Removed sensate information
      storage: /ssl-certs/acme.json
      caServer: 'https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

  production:
    acme:
      email: email@email.com # Removed sensate information
      storage: /ssl-certs/acme.json
      caServer: 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory'
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

# -- (Optional) Disable TLS Cert verification check
# serversTransport:
#   insecureSkipVerify: true

# -- (Optional) Overwrite Default Certificates
# tls:
#   stores:
#     default:
#       defaultCertificate:
#         certFile: /etc/traefik/certs/cert.pem
#         keyFile: /etc/traefik/certs/cert-key.pem
# -- (Optional) Disable TLS version 1.0 and 1.1
#   options:
#     default:
#       minVersion: VersionTLS12

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false

  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik
    watch: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing this problem because both traefik and portainer are trying to handle the HTTPS connection.
Try changing the port to `9000`(let traefik handle https):

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - private
    labels:
      # Frontend
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.mydomain.com`)' # Removed sensate information
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=production'
      - 'traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000'

volumes:
  portainer_data:
    external: true

networks:
  private:
    external: true
```